# How do I get piezoelectric constants from VASP?

Tags: vasp, vaspkit

I tried calculating Piezoelectric properties for a material using VASP with IBRION=8(DFPT) and LEPSILON=.true. . The piezoelectric tensors for ionic and electronic contributions turned out to be in the units of C/m^2 whereas the piezoelectric constants(d11,d12,...d33,...) i am looking for have the unit C/N. How do i calculate piezoelectric constants with units C/N from this?

I am attaching some screenshots of my output.
[image]

[image]

I referred some materials to solve this but I couldn’t find anything helpful as my knowledge of tensor is limited. Here is how i found the issue with my result:

> The constant
> for such a linearly proportional relation is defined as the piezoelectric coefficient
> d, which is a third-rank tensor coupling the first-rank tensor or vector (electric
> displacement or field) and the second-rank tensor (stress or strain). Hence, the
> piezoelectric equations may be written in the following form (i, j, k = 1, 2, 3)
> $D_k = d_{kij}T_{ij}$ 
> $S_{ij} = d_{kij}^*E_{k}$ 
> where $D_i$ is electric displacement $(C/m^2)$, $E_i$ is electric field component (V/m), $S_{ij}$ is strain component, $T_{ij}$ is stress component $(N/m^2)$, and $d_{kij}$ or $d_{kij}^*$ is component of the piezoelectric charge or strain constant.

I am ready to calculate it manually if i can learn how to do it from some source. But if you know any tools that can calculate the constants from this, please let me know about it as well.

Edit: Here is my INCAR:

```
#-------Global parameters ---------
LWAVE=.TRUE.
LCHARG=.TRUE.
ENCUT = 550
#PREC = Accurate
#ISTART = 1
LREAL= Auto
ALGO =  Fast
LORBIT=11
LEPSILON= .TRUE.

#--------- Electronic relaxation --------
ISMEAR = 0
SIGMA = 0.05
NELM = 60
NELMIN = 6
EDIFF = 0.0000001

#--------- Magnetic calculation ------------
ISPIN = 2
MAGMOM = 2*5 2*5 6*5

#------- IONIC Relaxation -----
NSW = 1
IBRION = 8
ISIF = 3

#-------- SLR ---------
POTIM = 0.015
```

- Here is a link to my [OUTCAR-github](https://github.com/vivekkarunakaran/Modeling_Matters/tree/master/12407)

Comment: Please copy and paste your code rather than sharing screenshots.

Comment: I can share my INCAR code. I will try to share a cloud link for my OUTPUT file as it is too large to be put  in here.

Comment: The INCAR will be useful. The problem with the screenshots that you shared, is that they are not searchable, or copy-pastable, and they are not even readable by people with some web browsers, or blind people that use screen readers. We prefer for you to insert your code as text, rather than than as a screenshot. I don't think the text in these screenshots will cause you to run out of space. Also, if you want to upload a file, please do it on GitHub as [instructed here](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/393/5).

Comment: @NikeDattani Thank you! I have attached them.

Comment: @Vivekkarunakaran, I just wonder based on the source you have quoted, based on the units, it looks like you are getting the electric displacement in VASP output, and to get the piezoelectric components you need to divide by Tij or the stress component.

Comment: @JaafarMehrez I felt the same. But i checked my output and it seems that they have given only the strain in it.